# How can I get the size of the cache in Spring-cache?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching, ehcache, spring-cache

How can I know the current cache size of the cache in spring-cache ?
I want to log when the cache size has reached maximum. I couldn't find a function which does that. How can I know ?

Answer (score 0):

Spring's Cache Abstraction does not deal with low level details.

You need to use a different cache implementation , you can see bunch of example from here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html#boot-features-caching-provider-simple

Comment: Do you have some implementation example which get the size of cache at present ?

Comment: unfortunately I've never tried before but from that URL implementations examples exists. You can find more details when you google one of them